# "Erase and remove _if " removes just last items

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, erase

I am facing problem while calling erase and remove_if on vectors like this:

```
best_angle_inliers.erase(
    std::remove_if(begin(best_angle_inliers), end(best_angle_inliers),
        [](line_helper<cv::Point> const& item){
            return item.the_line->segment_length() < 20;
        }
    ), end(best_angle_inliers)
);
```

Items that satisfy the condition and were placed originally at the back of the vectors are deleted. However, items that were placed originally in the middle were not deleted!

I know that you can not reproduce from this draft code. But any tiny hint is appreciated.

Comment: What's `line_helper`? Show its assignment operator.

Comment: @AngryLettuce Thanks for editing...  I mean items that were before applying this line in the middle of the vector for example at index 5 or 9 where the vector size is  20 for example

Comment: @T.C OMG!  assignment operator was return by value not reference! I do not know what to say! You rock! May you please add it as answer? and Please if you have time and you do not mind, may you post small hint how you figure that from the little information I provided

Comment: Since all `remove_if` does is a bunch of (move) assignments, that's the obvious first place to check. Though I actually don't know of any `remove_if` implementation that would break on a return-by-value assignment, so I still don't know what your actual cause of failure is... your error sounds like you have a no-op assignment, not a needlessly inefficient one.

Comment: I'm guessing `best_angle_inliers` isn't sorted.

Comment: @Simple Why does that matter? `remove_if` doesn't require a sorted range.

Comment: I'm thinking of `unique`. Nevermind.

Comment: How about providing an [MCVE](/help/mcve) in the future? Otherwise people just have to guess around about code that can't be seen in the question. An the reason for a lot of errors become obvious during the process of creating it.

Comment: @AngryLettuce: It doesn't actually move elements to the end of the container. It moves elements that are _not to be removed_ toward the beginning of the container. The "bad" elements are just overwritten as needed. It would take extra, unnecessary, work to move them to the end.